# Trying to find out how to load multiple image sequences in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I'm trying to build an app based on digitally animated drawn gestures.  I have made three sets of image sequences on transparent layers.  I want one image sequence to load as soon as the app opens and when that image sequence finishes, I'd like it to stay on the final frame and to trigger another random image sequence.  I'm fairly new to programming and have looked at tutorials about creating animations using image sequences in UIImageView but they're either written in Obj C or in Swift 1 whereas I'm working in Swift 2.0.  I can't successfully load one image sequence in Swift 2.0 yet.

Am I looking in the wrong direction?  Should I be looking at a different part of Swift 2.0?  Or are there tutorials on this out there that I just haven't found them yet?  Any help toward the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please show us what you have tried so far ... and take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare an array on UIImage.
There is a property of UIImageView called "animationImages". you can use it like this:

```
var animationImages:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1")!, UIImage(named: "image2")!, UIImage(named: "image3")!];
imageView.animationImages = animationImages;
imageView.animationDuration = NSTimeInterval(animationDuration);
imageView.startAnimating();
```

you can set a property called "animationRepeatCount" to whatever you like. 0(Zero) is for infinite loop.

Now as you know the animation duration and animation repeat count. You can easily calculate total time of animation:

```
var animationCompleteDelay = animationDuration * imageView.animationRepeatCount;
```

Then schedule a timer to fire after this total animation time.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(animationCompleteDelay, target: self, selector: "animationCompleteHandler:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That's super helpful.  I now have a full image sequence playing which is a huge leap forward!

Comment: I've been playing around with the animationRepeatCount and given it a value of 1 so that it only plays once.  

I tried the timer option but quickly realised that using a timer will mean that image sequences will load chronologically rather than randomly.  Is it possible to create an array of these image sequence arrays that can be triggered by a case?